# Django Form using Ajax and jQuery! Can't work out how to pass control from Ajax to Python in URL

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, email

How do I use a python file (project/controller/functions/email/sendemail.py) to process sending of an email (or any other task) from ajax using jQuery? Or am I going about it all wrong?

I don't want to redirect to another page like Django tuts teach, I want to refresh the form and show a success message only. (I have the messages and refresh of form working fine but not the handling of the URL in Ajax).

I have searched high and low on this and have come up trumps without anything useful. Some advice or links to examples would be appreciated.

My files are similar to below, except I am using jQuery Validate so a bit different but same principal and my form is laid out using bootstrap 3 on my version.

> index.html

```
<form method="post" action="sendemail" id="sendemail">
  <input name="name" type="text" />
  <input name="email" type="email" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

> main.js

```
$('form#sendemail').on('submit', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'), #(Targeting the action from the form. This is working as I can console.log the correct action as sendemail),
    type: type,
    data: data
  });
});
```

I tried redirecting my urls to target the file so I could use the URL from Ajax to target the file as below.

> urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from .controller.functions.email import sendemail

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.Home, name='home'),
  url(r'^sendemail', sendemail, name='sendemail'),
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

I get a 500 server error in my console with this.

> sendemail.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def sendemail(request):
  if (send_mail('Subject', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)):
    print(1) #Success
  else:
    print(99) #Fail
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from .forms import ContactForm

@csrf_protect
def Home(request):
  tpl = 'main/index.html'
  contactNotify = ""
  contactForm = request.POST


  if request.method == 'POST':
    contactForm = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if ContactForm.is_valid():
      return render(request, tpl, context)

  else:
    contactForm = ContactForm()

context = {
    'contactForm'       : contactForm
}

return render(request, tpl, context)
```

In php I use echo to return to jQuery so I presume print is it's equivalent in Python to return the value rather than return.

On Send I get the following log in console: 
POST http://localhost:8888/sendemail 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django works differently

```
<form method="post" action="{% 'sendemail' %}" id="sendemail">
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from .controller.functions.email import sendemail

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.Home, name='home'),
  url(r'^sendemail$/', views.sendemail_view, name='sendemail'),
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

views.py

```
from .helpers import sendemail

def sendemail_view(request):
    # here sendemail()
    # and return ALWAYS HttpResponse
```

and remember,

1. after urlconf match, django calls a function from views. this is how django is designed, views == controllers from another frameworks
2. django views function names should be lowercase always.

I dont know why you are listening to POST requests in your home views.. but I think there are more things to fix to get this to work, but please try my suggestions

Comment: I had to take the $ out of the url sendemail and it worked for me. Appreciate the support.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HttpResponse to return response to an ajax request.

```
import json
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse

def sendemail(request):
    data = {"message":"Failed"}
    if (send_mail('Subject', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)):
        data = {"message":"Success"}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

And if you are using Django 1.7+ then use **JsonResponse**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse(data)
```

The above code will return a json response, you will get this in ajax success function

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/

Comment: Thanks Anoop, I will use json layout from now. Much appreciated.